# WCF service host cannot find any service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

This is my first WCF.

I've looked everywhere but I could not read English at a sufficient level could not find the solution.

How can I solve this error?

**I've added the rest of the code**

Service1.cs:

```
namespace WcfJsonRestService
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   UriTemplate = "data/{Data}")]
        public DTResult GetData(string Data)
        { 
            DTResult result = new DTResult();
            try
            {
                result.Error = false;                                          
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ToString(); 
                DTResponse ResponseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTResponse>(DecodeFrom64(Data));
                result.DataSet = tvCore.Exec(connectionString, ResponseData.storedProcedure, ResponseData.parameters);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result.DataSet = null;
                result.Error = true;
                result.ErrorMsg = e.Message;
            }
            return result;

        }

        static public string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
        {
          byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
          string returnValue = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
          return returnValue;
        } 
    }



    /*
     *  MSSql Connect Class
     */
    public class tvCore
    {

        static public string Exec(string cntStr, string SP, dynamic[] param)
        {
            SqlConnection Cnt = new SqlConnection(cntStr); 
            DataTable Qry = new DataTable();
            DataSet DSet = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter SqlDataAdp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(SP, Cnt);
            SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Cnt.Open();
            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(SqlCmd);

            if (param.Length != SqlCmd.Parameters.Count-1)
                throw new Exception("Parameters lenght not match.");

            SqlCmd.Parameters.RemoveAt(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < SqlCmd.Parameters.Count; i++)
                if (SqlCmd.Parameters[i].SqlDbType == SqlDbType.DateTime)
                    SqlCmd.Parameters[i].Value = param[i] == null ? DBNull.Value : DateTime.ParseExact(param[i], "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
                else
                    SqlCmd.Parameters[i].Value = param[i] == null ? DBNull.Value : param[i];  

            SqlDataReader reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            //DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
            //schema.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { schema.Columns["ColumnOrdinal"] };

            string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reader, new DTConvert());

            reader.Close();
            Cnt.Close();
           // SqlDataAdp.SelectCommand = SqlCmd;
           // SqlDataAdp.FillSchema(DSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
           // SqlDataAdp.Fill(Qry);

            return result;        
        }
    }


    /* 
     * DataTable To JSon Class
     */
    public class DTConvert : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(System.Type objectType)
        {
            //Return objectType = GetType(DataTable)
            return typeof(SqlDataReader).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        } 

        public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

            SqlDataReader reader = value as SqlDataReader;
            int ncols = reader.FieldCount;
            DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

            writer.WriteStartObject();

            #region Columns
            writer.WritePropertyName("Columns");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach( DataRow col in schema.Rows )
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                string field = "AllowDBNull";

                writer.WritePropertyName(field);
                writer.WriteValue(col[field]);

                field = "IsAutoincrement";
                writer.WritePropertyName(field);
                writer.WriteValue(col[field]);

                field = "ColumnName";
                writer.WritePropertyName(field);
                writer.WriteValue(col[field]);

                field = "DataType";
                writer.WritePropertyName(field);
                writer.WriteValue((col[field] as Type).Name);

                field = "ColumnSize";
                writer.WritePropertyName(field);
                writer.WriteValue(col[field]);

                field = "isReadOnly";
                writer.WritePropertyName(field);
                writer.WriteValue(col[field]);

                field = "isUnique";
                writer.WritePropertyName(field);
                writer.WriteValue(col[field]);

                writer.WriteEndObject();

            }

            writer.WriteEndArray();
            #endregion

            #region Rows     
            writer.WritePropertyName("Rows");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(reader.GetName(i));
                    writer.WriteValue(reader[i]);
                }
                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }         
            writer.WriteEndArray();
            #endregion

            writer.WriteEndObject();

        }


        public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();            
            return table;
        }   
    }

    public class DTResult
    {
        public string DataSet { get; set; }
        public bool Error { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMsg { get; set; } 
    }

    public class DTResponse
    {
        public string storedProcedure { get; set; }
        public dynamic[] parameters { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

App.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration> 
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="db" connectionString="Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DBNAME;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings> 
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1">
                <endpoint address="http://localhost/iPadWcf"
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          contract="WcfJsonRestService.IService1"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior> 
                    <webHttp />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `IService1` ??? Post it's definition.

Comment: I assume this isn't working? Can you let us know what is wrong, and that will help people give you a simple answer

Comment: @kschieck  "WCF service host cannot find any service metadata"

Comment: @BarışAtalay Have you read my comment?

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming, that you are looking for a way to create RESTful WebService.
Here is a little help, I've created as one of my practices.

If you have a store, and willing to get informations about products, you have to send a request by the client to the WebService to serve it. You have to define few things in the Web.config.

In the  add

```
<services>
      <service name="RestService_Production.RestService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService_Production.IRestService" />
      </service>
</services
```

and

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Assume, you have a method like this

```
public interface IRestService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                UriTemplate = "product/{id}")]
    Product GetProductInformations(string id);
}
```

And in the .svc, you have to define it like this

```
public Product GetProductInformations(string id)
    {
        return new Product();
    }
```

You can make a request to the Rest service, by

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Remote remote = new Remote(endPoint, methodType, methodName, methodData);

        string requestUri = remote.GetEndPoint() + remote.GetMethodName() + remote.GetDataPost();
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

        request.Method = remote.GetMethodType();
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";

        Console.WriteLine("Wait until the WebService starts and then press a key to continue!");
        Console.ReadKey();

        try
        {
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream getResponseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponseStream);
            string friendlyResponse = GenerateFriendlyJson(sr.ReadToEnd());

            var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var product = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(friendlyResponse);

            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + product["Name"] +
                            ", Description: " + product["Description"] +
                            ", Price: " + product["Price"] +
                            ", Quantity: " + product["Quantity"]);
        }
        catch (WebException wEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not access to network through protocol: \n" + wEx.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception cEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Some common excepion happened: \n" + cEx.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Where the GET methodType is a "GET", "POST", "PUT" or "DELETE" string, the name is like "product/", and the data is like anything that fits to a string.
The endPoint should look like this: "ht.tp://(your host):10064/RestService.svc/" (I had to change it, because SO didn't allow links)

I hope it helped. If you have any problems, I will upload that project to Git or something.

Comment: Since the question was, how can he solve his problem, this is a way to solve it. The client code was just a bit more extension.

Comment: No, the question was how to solve his _actual_ problem. I don't even see where  you are hosting the service.

Comment: As he cannot create a whole, understandable question, i'm assuming he cannot even create a simple example. So it is his actual problem. If you look closely, it is in the localhost.

Comment: Did you not see that he is trying to _host_ the service?